# chi-squared test statistic implementation in python

Tags: probability, statistics, python

I am tasked with creating a script version of a spreadsheet which does overall model testing of satellite measurements for land subsidence. In one particular cell of this spreadsheet, I see a formula as follows. Although it is not explicitly stated, I suspect that the cell is calculating a chi-squared test statistic:

$$\chi^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(z_i-z_{regr,i})^2}{\sigma_{assumed}^2}$$

I have done a bit of research into `python` libraries from which to generate this result because the idea of the script is to code as little as possible from scratch. Unfortunately, all online resources show that the test statistic is calculated as follows:

$$\chi^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(z_i-z_{regr,i})^2}{z_{regr, i}}$$

Part of the idea of this spreadsheet is that the standard deviation must be a user-defined input, and I cannot reconciliate that with the above formula. Furthermore, common `python` methods such as `scipy.stats.chisquare` only have the following mathematical inputs:

```
f_obs : array_like
    Observed frequencies in each category.
f_exp : array_like, optional
    Expected frequencies in each category.  By default the categories are
    assumed to be equally likely.
ddof : int, optional
    "Delta degrees of freedom": adjustment to the degrees of freedom
    for the p-value.  The p-value is computed using a chi-squared
    distribution with ``k - 1 - ddof`` degrees of freedom, where `k`
    is the number of observed frequencies.  The default value of `ddof`
    is 0.
```

And the following outputs:

```
chisq : float or ndarray
    The chi-squared test statistic.  The value is a float if `axis` is
    None or `f_obs` and `f_exp` are 1-D.
p : float or ndarray
    The p-value of the test.  The value is a float if `ddof` and the
    return value `chisq` are scalars.
```

And never require standard deviation as input.

My question is twofold:

- Is the first equation that I am showing correct? Why then is it different than the chi-squared test statistic provided in literature?
- If the first equation is correct, how can I use functions such as `scipy.stats.chisquare` to evaluate it, namely with an assumed $\sigma$?

Thanks

Comment: The difference lies in the assumption you make about how the $z$'s are distributed. In the first case, one probably assumes normally distributed $z$, probably a real value + a measurement error. The second case is a formula that applies for categorical variables in some limit of large numbers. Since your problem is about "satellite measurement for land subsidence", I suspect it's really the first formula you need.

Comment: In background material for the first formula, we have "The test statistic $T$ follows a chi squared distribution with $q$ degrees of freedom: $T = \chi^2(q,0)$. So I think your first statement might be incorrect? It is not normally distributed...

Comment: I never said the test statistic is normally distributed. Read again. Besides, what is $q$ here? I only see $n$ in your problem formulation. If you are not sure what you're doing, I'd advise you to consult with a statistician.

Comment: So the distribution of the test statistic does not have to follow the distribution of the $z$'s? You're statement implies that the test statistic can have a chi2 distribution while the data itself (the $z$'s) have a normal distribution. $q$ is the degrees of freedom, and $q = n - m$ where $m$ is the number of unknowns and $n$ is the number of observations. There are only 2 unknowns here since we are dealing with linear regression ((intercept and slope).

Comment: No, it doesn't have to. Consult with a statistician. You're obviously doing this for a job, it's only fair that you ask for direct expert advice and not just with a random person on a board.

Comment: I can ask wherever I want @Raskolnikov. There are plenty of good statisticians here and this platform is as good as any other. If you don't wish to answer or help then that is totally fine with me.